# Pomodoro Timer in Basic JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I am a beginner in JavaScript and new on stackoverflow, am working on a project Pomodoro Timer to build something like this 
http://codepen.io/GeoffStorbeck/full/RPbGxZ/

But am stuck on its functionality on how to make the session countdown and wait for the breaklength countdown before it starts counting again, this is how far I have gone http://codepen.io/Lumexralph/pen/qbqJKq/

```js
var breakLength = 5,
  session = 20; //starts the time on break
var show = document.getElementById('displayBreak'); //get the elements to show the time
show.textContent = breakLength; //puts the var as the textcontent

var showSession = document.getElementById('displaySession'); //get the elements to show the time
showSession.textContent = session; //puts the var as the textcontent

var sessionCountdown = document.getElementById('sessionCount'); // for counting session
sessionCountdown.textContent = session;

function subtraction() {
  //to increase the starting variable
  breakLength -= 1;
  var displayLength = document.getElementById('displayBreak');
  displayLength.textContent = breakLength;
}

function addition() {
    //to increase the starting variable
    breakLength += 1;
    var displayLength = document.getElementById('displayBreak');
    displayLength.textContent = breakLength;
  }
  /*functions to add and reduce the session time*/

function sessionSubtraction() { // to reduce sessiontime
  session -= 1;
  //for session div
  var holdSession = document.getElementById('displaySession');
  holdSession.textContent = session;
  //for session countdown
  var holdSessionCount = document.getElementById('sessionCount');
  holdSessionCount.textContent = session;
}

function sessionAddition() { // to reduce sessiontime
    session += 1;
    //for session div
    var holdSession = document.getElementById('displaySession');
    holdSession.textContent = session;
    //for session count
    var holdSessionCount = document.getElementById('sessionCount');
    holdSessionCount.textContent = session;
  }
  //function to start the countdown

function countdown() {
  var sessionData = document.getElementById('sessionCount').textContent;
  sessionData--;
  setTimeout('countdown()', 1000);
}

//add event listener click
var timeCount = document.getElementById('sessionCount');
timeCount.addEventListener('click', countdown, false);
//adding event hlisteners for lengthbreak
var showBreak = document.getElementById('plusButton');
showBreak.addEventListener('click', addition, false);

var showBreak = document.getElementById('minusButton');
showBreak.addEventListener('click', subtraction, false);

//event for session
var sessionLength = document.getElementById('minusSession');
sessionLength.addEventListener('click', sessionSubtraction, false);

var sessionLength = document.getElementById('plusSession');
sessionLength.addEventListener('click', sessionAddition, false);
```

```html
<div id='displayBreak'></div>
<p>Break Length</p>
<button type='button' id='minusButton'>minus</button>
<!--decreases the stored variable-->
<button type='button' id='plusButton'>plus</button>
<!--increses the stored variable-->
<p>Session Length</p>
<div id='displaySession'></div>
<button type='button' id='minusSession'>minus</button>
<!--decreases the stored variable-->
<button type='button' id='plusSession'>plus</button>
<!--increses the stored variable-->
<p>Session</p>
<div id='sessionCount'></div>
```

Comment: what is the question here?

Comment: Have you searched SO to research the problem at all? Pomodoro timers have had quite a few posts

Comment: i did but not really answering my questions.

Answer (score 0):

Your *countdown* function needs to be like this:

```
    function countdown() {
      var sessionData =  document.getElementById('sessionCount').textContent;
      sessionData--;
      document.getElementById('sessionCount').innerHTML = sessionData;
      setTimeout('countdown()', 1000);
}
```

You forgot to update the variable on the "sessionCount" div. And for that reason your countdown was not updated.

Comment: isn't supposed to be 'timeCount.addEventListener('click', countdown, false);', if you do it your way, its going to get invoked immediately and only once

Comment: Yes you are right. Your eventListener is correct. Sorry :)